# Encoded delegate calls fails

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, delegatecall

I have been using `encodeFunctionCall()` utils for encoding my function call. when i use the encoded data to execute delegateCall(), it gets reverted.

My solidity call is like

```
bool success, ) = IAPContract(APContract)
            .getStrategyFromMinter(msg.sender)
            .delegatecall(hexUtils.fromHex(data));
            revertDelegate(success);
```

My javascript encoding is like

```
let instruction = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(
      {
        name: "withdrawalCleanUp",
        type: "function",
        inputs: [
          {
            type: "address[]",
            name: "_strategies",
          },
          {
            type: "address[]",
            name: "_withdrawalAssets",
          },
          {
            type: "uint256[]",
            name: "_shares",
          },
        ],
      },
      [
        ["0xbb4f366AEEeb9ec7b9e64bc4960C03AfB868d883"],
        ["0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"],
        [to18("100")],
      ]
    );
await Minter.methods
      .mintStrategy(
        vaultAddress,
        instruction
      )
      .send({ from: "0x5091aF48BEB623b3DA0A53F726db63E13Ff91df9" })
```

I was able to call function without parameters by this method

Comment: There's not enough to test. What's `data` type? What does `hexUtils.fromHex` do? Does the strategy implement `withdrawalCleanUp`?

Comment: Yes, Strategy do implement withdrawal clean up, fromHex("x") converts bytes to hexString. data types are as in input , address[],address[],uint256[]